# MKPolyLine Swift 4

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpolyline, swift4

I am trying to learn `MapKit` and add some `MKPolyLine` as an overlay. Couple of questions:

1. What is the difference between `MKPolyLine` and `MKPolyLineView`. Which one should be used when?
2. For the `MKPolyLine` init method one of the parameter is a generic type(`MKMapPoint`) of `UnsafePointer`? Not really sure what is that supposed to mean. Looking up the various SO questions, it seems we are supposed to pass the memory address of the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct as a parameter, but it doesn't work for me.

   ```
   let testline = MKPolyline()
   let coords1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.167894, longitude: 17.077399)
   let coords2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.168776, longitude: 17.081326)
   let coords3 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.167921, longitude: 17.083730)
   let testcoords:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [coords1,coords2,coords3]


   let line = MKPolyline.init(points: &testcoords, count: testcoords.count)

   mapView.add(testline)
   ```

I keep getting a `"& is not allowed passing array value as 'UnsafePointer<MKMapPoint>" argument"`.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 12):

***1.***

`MKPolyLine` is a class which holds multiple map-coordinates to define the shape of a polyline, very near to just an array of coordinates.
`MKPolyLineView` is a view class which manages the visual representation of the `MKPolyLine`. As mentioned in the [Kane Cheshire's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068460/6541007), it's outdated and you should use `MKPolyLineRenderer`.

**Which one should be used when?**

You need to use both `MKPolyLine` and `MKPolyLineRenderer` as in the code below.

---

***2.***

[`MKPolyLine`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline) has two initializers:

- [`init(points: UnsafePointer<MKMapPoint>, count: Int)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline/1452773-init)
- [`init(coordinates: UnsafePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: Int)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolyline/1452205-init)

When you want to pass `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]` to `MKPolyLine.init`, you need to use `init(coordinates:count:)`.

(Or you can create an Array of `MKMapPoint` and pass it to `init(points:count:)`.)

And when you want to pass an immutable Array (declared with `let`) to `UnsafePointer` (non-Mutable), you have no need to prefix `&`.

---

The code below is actually built and tested with Xcode 9 beta 3:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let coords1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.167894, longitude: 17.077399)
        let coords2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.168776, longitude: 17.081326)
        let coords3 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.167921, longitude: 17.083730)
        let testcoords:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [coords1,coords2,coords3]

        let testline = MKPolyline(coordinates: testcoords, count: testcoords.count)
        //Add `MKPolyLine` as an overlay.
        mapView.add(testline)

        mapView.delegate = self

        mapView.centerCoordinate = coords2
        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coords2, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        //Return an `MKPolylineRenderer` for the `MKPolyline` in the `MKMapViewDelegate`s method
        if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
            let testlineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
            testlineRenderer.strokeColor = .blue
            testlineRenderer.lineWidth = 2.0
            return testlineRenderer
        }
        fatalError("Something wrong...")
        //return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `testCoords` to be `var` instead of `let`. It needs to be mutable (variable) to be passed in as a pointer.

You're also trying to pass an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s into an argument that expects an array of `MKMapPoint`s. Either convert your coordinates into points or use the function that takes an array of coordinates instead.

`MKPolyLineView` is an old way of rendering lines onto maps, Apple's docs say to use `MKPolylineRenderer` from iOS 7 and onwards: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpolylineview

Comment: why cant i just use "&" just like in objC

Comment: Because this is Swift and not Objective-C. Everything is mutable in Objective-C, in Swift `let` means it can't be changed. 

Arrays are also structs in Swift and classes in Objective-C.

All you have to do is change `let` to `var` in your code, leave the `&` where it is.

Comment: changed let to var..still fails with cannot convert value to 'unsafepointer<MKMapPoint>

Comment: You're passing coordinates into an argument that is expecting points. Either change to use MKMapPoint like the error says or use `MKPolyline(coordinates: &testCoords, count: testCoords.count)`

Comment: You have no need to change `let` to `var` when passing Swift Array to `UnsafePointer` (non-mutable). Use `let` and remove `&`.

Comment: Hmm, so I just tried with `let` and it doesn't compile. When I change to `var` it does.

Comment: Have you included _remove `&`_? As far as I tested on Xcode 9 beta 3, it compiles without any problems